# Screen Transition: How to always move from left-to-right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, transition

I am developing a phone application and I have two buttons at the top of the screen: "back" and "next". Whenever I click the next button the screen moves from right-to-left and most of the time I click the back button, it moves from left-to-right; however, every so often, clicking 'back' transitions from right-to-left.

This is the code that i have for the back button:

.html

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back"  data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="myTransition" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
```

.js

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

$.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText  = "Back";
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn   = false;
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnTheme = null;
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.headerTheme  = "a";
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.footerTheme  = "a";
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.contentTheme = null;

$( document ).delegate( ":jqmData(role='page'), :jqmData(role='dialog')", "pagecreate", function( e ) {

var $page = $( this ),
    o = $page.data( "page" ).options,
    pageRole = $page.jqmData( "role" ),
    pageTheme = o.theme;

$( ":jqmData(role='header'), :jqmData(role='footer'), :jqmData(role='content')", this ).each(function() {
    var $this = $( this ),
        role = $this.jqmData( "role" ),
        theme = $this.jqmData( "theme" ),
        contentTheme = theme || o.contentTheme || ( pageRole === "dialog" && pageTheme ),
        $headeranchors,
        leftbtn,
        rightbtn,
        backBtn;

    $this.addClass( "ui-" + role ); 

    //apply theming and markup modifications to page,header,content,footer
    if ( role === "header" || role === "footer" ) {

        var thisTheme = theme || ( role === "header" ? o.headerTheme : o.footerTheme ) || pageTheme;

        $this
            //add theme class
            .addClass( "ui-bar-" + thisTheme )
            // Add ARIA role
            .attr( "role", role === "header" ? "banner" : "contentinfo" );

        // Right,left buttons
        $headeranchors  = $this.children( "a" );
        leftbtn = $headeranchors.hasClass( "ui-btn-left" );
        rightbtn = $headeranchors.hasClass( "ui-btn-right" );

        leftbtn = leftbtn || $headeranchors.eq( 0 ).not( ".ui-btn-right" ).addClass( "ui-btn-left" ).length;

        rightbtn = rightbtn || $headeranchors.eq( 1 ).addClass( "ui-btn-right" ).length;

        // Auto-add back btn on pages beyond first view
        if ( o.addBackBtn && 
            role === "header" &&
            $( ".ui-page" ).length > 1 &&
            $this.jqmData( "url" ) !== $.mobile.path.stripHash( location.hash ) &&
            !leftbtn ) {

            backBtn = $( "<a href='#' class='ui-btn-left' data-"+ $.mobile.ns +"rel='back' data-"+ $.mobile.ns +"icon='arrow-l'>"+ o.backBtnText +"</a>" )
                // If theme is provided, override default inheritance
                .attr( "data-"+ $.mobile.ns +"theme", o.backBtnTheme || thisTheme )
                .prependTo( $this );                
        }

        // Page title
        $this.children( "h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6" )
            .addClass( "ui-title" )
            // Regardless of h element number in src, it becomes h1 for the enhanced page
            .attr({
                "tabindex": "0",
                "role": "heading",
                "aria-level": "1"
            });

    } else if ( role === "content" ) {
        if ( contentTheme ) {
            $this.addClass( "ui-body-" + ( contentTheme ) );
        }

        // Add ARIA role
        $this.attr( "role", "main" );
    }
});
});

})( jQuery );
```

EDIT:

this is the transition that i created

```
function myTransitionHandler( name, reverse, $to, $from ) {

var deferred = new $.Deferred(),
    reverseClass = reverse ? " reverse" : "",
    viewportClass = "ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning viewport-" + name,
    doneFunc = function() {

        $to.add( $from ).removeClass( "out in reverse " + name );

        if ( $from && $from[ 0 ] !== $to[ 0 ] ) {
            $from.removeClass( $.mobile.activePageClass );
        }

        $to.parent().removeClass( viewportClass );

        deferred.resolve( name, reverse, $to, $from );
    };

$to.animationComplete( doneFunc );

$to.parent().addClass( viewportClass );

if ( $from ) {
    $from.addClass( name + " out" + reverseClass );
}
$to.addClass( $.mobile.activePageClass + " " + name + " in" + reverseClass );

return deferred.promise();
}

// Make our transition handler public.
$.mobile.transitionHandlers["myTransition"] = myTransitionHandler;
```

Is there any code that I can add to make the screen always move from left-to-right when the back button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile appears to only allow you to specify a transition ([seen here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)) and then program for its opposite for when you specify the `data-direction="reverse"` property.

I have also experienced this behavior that the back-button (even the browser's back-button) can sometimes trigger a 'forward acting' transition. I'm not how one would go about changing this / forcing a button to transition always in the same direction.

However, there might be some promise in [setting up your own transitions](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-customtransitions.html). If you were to do that, (which I haven't) then you might be able to apply a transition that only goes one direction whether jQuery mobile believes it is forward or reversed and regardless of the `data-direction` property.

```
.my.slide.out {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
    -moz-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
}
.my.slide.in {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
    -moz-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
}
```

And then apply these transitions to your back-button.

Comment: i tried to add my own transition to the page but this made no difference to the way the page moved

Comment: @HipHipArray; did you specify the `data-transition` property to be the name of the new transition you created? You might want to update your question with what you have tried. You should do something drastically different than whatever is the default until you're sure you are using the transition you created.

Comment: ya I did add my created transition to the data-transition property... i will edit my question and add what i created

Comment: @HipHipArray; thanks for updating the question but I don't see your transition definition -- just the transition handler. My suggestion is still that you would do something drastically different than a slide left/right until you're sure you have hooked up your properties to your custom transition. Until you are sure it is using yours, it may just be falling back to the default transition. Perhaps try creating a custom color 'transition', fade, etc... when you are confident it is using yours, you can then dispense of using the reverse property and just always transition left-to-right.

Comment: sorry ya i have the transition definition done as weel, i will add that the next edit but ya that is a very good idea, i will try change the transition dramatically so that i can make sure that it is working and then change it to moving how i want.. will let you know how i get on and update my answer

Comment: @HipHipArray, did you ever figure out what went wrong? Did this idea get you towards your solution or did you come up with a different solution? You should post your own answer or accept this one accordingly.

Comment: no, i never figured this out. As it is not that big of a deal, after a few days of trying i just gave up as it was not worth the time that i was putting into, so the problem is still there

Comment: @HipHipArray; great! Thanks for reporting back an update. You might want to update your question to this status so anyone coming across it in the future knows that a solution is still forthcoming.